While making a build on react native app on my mac iOS system i am getting this error
Please guide me with the error
Failed to upload the project tarball to EAS Build Reason: EPERM: operation not permitted, scandir '/Users/agrahyah/.Trash' Error: build command failed.
I have used this command to build an.apk file for my app through this command
sudo eas build -p android --profile preview

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
